Dynamically show/hide columns in reactable table based on external range
I would like to show/hide columns dynamically in a reactable table using an external range. I'm aware that long format is preferred, but I need to have the data in wide format.
Here is my code so far:
# Create table

dummy_data <- data.frame("Metric" = c("Sales", "Profits"), `2019` = c(75.6, 58.4), `2020` = c(65.8, 49.0), `2021` = c(72.3, 61.4)) %>%
  rename(`2019` = X2019, `2020` = X2020, `2021` = X2021)

reactable(dummy_data, elementId = "dummy-table")

# Create external range
browsable(
  tagList(
    div(
      tags$label(`for` = "min", id = "minLabel", "2019"),
      tags$input(type = "range", min = colnames(dummy_data)[2], max = colnames(dummy_data)[4], value = colnames(dummy_data)[2], step = 1, id = "min",
                 oninput = JS("var minLabel = document.getElementById('minLabel');
                                                              let value = this.value;
                                                              minLabel.innerText = value;")),
      tags$label(`for` = "max", id = "maxLabel", "2021"),
      tags$input(type = "range", min = colnames(dummy_data)[2], max = colnames(dummy_data)[4], value = colnames(dummy_data)[4], step = 1, id = "max",
                 oninput = JS("var maxLabel = document.getElementById('maxLabel');
                                                              let value = this.value;
                                                              maxLabel.innerText = value;")))))

I would like to have the columns visible/invisible be dynamically controlled through the external range.
